# Emit listener gets removed from $attrs when event is declared in emits option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Vue 3 introduced the option to declare a components emitted events in the `emits` option, while also removing the `$listeners` attribute in favor of the `$attrs`.

In `$attrs` event listeners for events get added an prefixed with `on` so an event called `click` is accessed in the component through `$attrs.onClick`. But when the click events is declared in the `emits` option, it dissapears from `$attrs`.

Answer (score 2):

This is made by design in Vue 3, since the `$attrs` attribute only is meant to include things not declared in the component.

If you want to access the components event listeners, while having them declared, you can add a prop with the same name as the event prefixed with `on` and propagate the function into the component like a prop, like mentioned [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/397#discussioncomment-5754225).

There's also a discussion on the Vue.js core Github about this behaviour [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/397). Edit: The discussion has been stale for a while and it looks like the behaviour is here to stay.